# populating a aggregate table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a question

### target table

```
str_week_day end_week_day  age_id usage_ratio eq_type
------------ ------------  ------ ----------- -------
11-Jul-10    17-Jul-10       1.00         0.5 RECEIVER
11-Jul-10    17-Jul-10       2.00         0.5 HUB
18-Jul-10    24-jul-10       1.00         0.5 RECEIVER
18-Jul-10    24-jul-10       2.00         0.5 HUB
.......
......
and so on
```

### source table

```
Start_date End_Date     age_id  eq_type
---------- --------     ------  ------- 
13-Jul-10  30-Jul-10      1.00  RECEIVER
15-Jul-10  25-Jul-10      2.00  HUB
```

ill give the sample

**source_data**

```
DIM_PANELIST_ID E E_SERIAL_NMBR DIM_PANEL_ID     AGE_ID BEGIN_DATE   END_DATE P_BEGIN_DATE INSERT_TS                                                           UPDATE_TS
--------------- - ------------- ------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
              1 M        172241           12          2       1616       1742          977 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              1 R        812890           12          2       1616       1742          977 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              2 M        154918           12          3       1560       1639          894 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              2 M        275351           12          3       1483       1560          894 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              3 M        155758           12          3       1560       1639          894 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              4 M        240087           12          4       1508       1557         1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              4 M        151575           12          4       1557       1601         1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              4 M        116520           12          4       1602                    1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              5 M        158929           12          4       1576       1588          868 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              6 R        812346           12          4       1621       1676         1112 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              6 M        170735           12          4       1621       1676         1112 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              7 M        279409           12          4       1662       1686          944 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              7 M        272720           12          4       1508       1661          944 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 M        194139           12          5       1712                    1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 M        279839           12          5       1484       1511         1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 R        319711           12          5       1512       1620         1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 R        812067           12          5       1620                    1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 M        274505           12          5       1512       1620         1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              8 M        171353           12          5       1620       1709         1155 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              9 M        173784           12          5       1617                    1315 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
              9 R        814566           12          5       1617                    1315 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
             10 M        154363           12          5       1557                    1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
             11 M        145473           12          5       1558                    1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
             11 R        322260           12          5       1558                    1324 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM
             12 M        158807           12          5       1576       1588          868 13-JUL-10 09.07.35.000000 PM                                                13-JUL-10
```

**expected_target_data**

```
STR_WK_DAY  END_WK_DAY  EQ_TYPE USAGE_RATIO
4-Jan-09      10-Jan-09   R   0.5
4-Jan-09      10-Jan-09   M   0.5
11-Jan-09     17-Jan-09   M   1
18-Jan-09     24-Jan-09   M   1
18-Jan-09     24-Jan-09   M   1
18-Jan-09     24-Jan-09   M   1
```

the data in the target is not accurate except the date's

I want to populate the target table I don’t know how to populate it 
The couple of scripts I have tried are

Mfrp1 table is the source table

```
select (select count(*) 
         from mfrp1 
         where aid=a.aid )/(select count(*) 
                             from mfrp1) as ratio
       , a.aid as ageid
       , (case when a.m>a.r then 'M' else 'R'end) as eq_type
from  (select  aid
                , sum(case when eq_type='M'then 1 else 0 end) as "M",
                  sum(case when eq_type='R'then 1 else 0 end) as "R"            
      from mfrp1 group by aid) a;
```

Comment: in order to populate you need to INSERT.

Comment: You should tell us what business logic you are trying to implement, rather than showing us some (sorry) half-baked SQL and leaving us to guess the rules.  For instance, where do the start and end dates come from?

Comment: sorry about that the start and end dates are system gnerated, the str_week_day and the end_week_day are to be generated.starting from the trunc(min(start_date)) -to_char(min(start_date),'D') +1

Answer (score 0):

To populate a table you need to INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
  (
    str_week_day,
    end_week_day,
    age_id,
    eq_type
  )

SELECT
   start_date,
   end_date,
   age_id,
   eq_type
FROM
   SourceTable
```

Comment: sorry about the select and the insert confusion .. i have edited my reuirements

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a view instead of a table? The CREATE VIEW statement is just a query, and the same query you'd use to populate the table would do to define the view. The view won't become out of date.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonH stated, you need to use an insert to populate a table.  Making a number of assumptions, your query might look like this:

```
insert into Target_Table
       (str_week_day, end_week_day, age_id, usage_ratio eq_type)
select str_week_day,
       week_start+6 as end_week_day
       a.aid as age_id,
       a.cnt/m.cnt as usage_ratio,
       (case when a.m>a.r then 'M' else 'R'end) as eq_type
from
      (select aid,
              sum(case when eq_type='M'then 1 else 0 end) as "M",
              sum(case when eq_type='R'then 1 else 0 end) as "R" ,
              count(*) as cnt,
              trunc(start_date,"D") as str_week_day
       from mfrp1 
       group by aid, 
                trunc(start_date,"D")) a,
      (select count(*) as cnt from mfrp1) m;
```

However, as @Brian Hooper stated, you'd be much better off with a view.  As he mentioned, the view would be always be consistent with the source data, as it is simply a stored query that runs against that data on demand.  As a view is accessed in exactly the same manner as a table, they are mostly indistinguishable to a user (be it a person or an application).

```
create or replace view Target_Table as
select str_week_day,
       week_start+6 as end_week_day
       a.aid as age_id,
       a.cnt/m.cnt as usage_ratio,
       (case when a.m>a.r then 'M' else 'R'end) as eq_type
from
      (select aid,
              sum(case when eq_type='M'then 1 else 0 end) as "M",
              sum(case when eq_type='R'then 1 else 0 end) as "R" ,
              count(*) as cnt,
              trunc(start_date,"D") as str_week_day
       from mfrp1 
       group by aid, 
                trunc(start_date,"D")) a,
      (select count(*) as cnt from mfrp1) m;
```

If this is too slow, you might consider a materialized view, which will do a lot of the work of keeping the aggregated data up-to-date, but stores the data separately to speed access.  In most cases, this isn't necessary though.